# Bootstrap Carousel width bigger than picture

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: the picture of slide]

I use carousel in Bootstrap to realize the sliding picture effect, but however, when the width of window become larger, the box of slide become larger while the width of picture region stays original.

How do modify the code to put the lefter margin of box to left margin of picture when the width is too much for picture?

Edit: the demo address: http://zgzhen.freeshell.ustc.edu.cn/posters/nctu2013

the effect i want: the auto-resize of carousel box so that the control panel on the right won't be out of range.

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
</ol>

<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active">
  <img src="../images/upload/nctu/1.png" alt="...">
</div>
<!-- other pictures-->
</div>
<!-- Controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev"></a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next"></a>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to *center* the image in the div?

Comment: No exactly. Since the right margin of "click" region is out of picture , I want it back to the picture.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I'm sorry, please see the words added :)

Comment: So you want the div to resize to fit the contents?

Comment: Yes, the content have its maximum pixel width

Comment: Mark's answer is correct in this case then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is not clear enough, do you want to centre the image or want to fill the image. Please try this and let me know for more assistance. Paste the below code in your CSS Stylesheet.

```
.carousel-inner .item img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: it works. The picture has resized itself to adopt the screen.

Comment: Just to add, note that on line 5151 of your "twitter-boostrap.css" you have a similar rule: `max-width: 100%`. This does **nothing** *because* the images are natively smaller than the width of the container. Adding `width: 100%` *forces* them to fill the container. Good answer +1.

Comment: Glad I can help, please this answer.